# Adding an object to an array within object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, javascript-objects

I'm pretty new to Javascript, but I want to create a game. In the game, every time a user plays or completes a certain level they'll accumulate points (sort of like an achievement or badge). I need to write an algorithm that will not only keep track of the user's points, but will assign them the correct badge after they've completed an action and/or have earned the necessary points.

I was thinking along the lines of creating a User object for each player that will include properties such as 'name', 'points', and an array listing the badges the player has earned so far. The badges themselves will also be objects and there will be certain properties describing the rank.

Is it possible to push an object inside of another object in Javascript? For example:

```
var daniel = {
  userName: "Daniel White",
  userPoints: 1250,
  userBadges = [ 'Bronze', 'Silver' ],
 }

var goldBadge = {
  badgeName: "Gold",
  minWeight: 1250,
}
```

Note: The 'minWeight' property is stating that the user must have a minimum of 1250 points in order to obtain that badge.

Is it possible for me to assign the gold badge to user Daniel by pushing goldBadge to the array userBadges? Or am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: I would say...yes to both. You totally *can* push gold on to badges, but if points are the only determinant for badges then just make a function that takes an integer and returns an array of badges: `const getBadges = n => [["gold", 1250], ["silver", 1000]].filter(([name, thres]) => thres <= n).map(([name] => name);`. Using object properties might be *conceptually* simple, but you're storing a lot of duplicate data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use `push` method

```js
var daniel = {
  userName: "Daniel White",
  userPoints: 1250,
  userBadges: ['Bronze', 'Silver']
}

var goldBadge = {
  badgeName: "Gold",
  minWeight: 1250
}
daniel.userBadges.push(goldBadge);
console.log(daniel)
```

Comment: Simple enough. Thank you!

Comment: You could do that but then the data structure is very odd and inconsistent because it contains two strings and one object.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to assign the gold badge to user Daniel by pushing goldBadge to the array userBadges? Or am I going about it all wrong?

Yeah in javascript it is possible to have an array of different types. In this case:

```
var daniel = {
  userName: "Daniel White",
  userPoints: 1250,
  userBadges : ['Bronze', 'Silver']}

var goldBadge = {
  badgeName: "Gold",
  minWeight: 1250}

daniel.userBadges.push(goldBadge)
```

Comment: Simple enough! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply `push` it to the `userBadges` property.

Like this:

```
var daniel = {
  userName: "Daniel White",
  userPoints: 1250,
  userBadges = [ 'Bronze', 'Silver' ],
 }


daniel.userBadges.push({
  badgeName: "Gold",
  minWeight: 1250,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to assign the gold badge to user Daniel by pushing goldBadge to the array userBadges? Or am I going about it all wrong?

I would say...yes to both. You totally *can* push gold on to badges (the other answers show how to do so), but if points are the only determinant for badges then just make a function that takes an integer and returns an array of badges:

```
const badges = [["gold", 1250], ["silver", 1000], /* etc */];
const getBadgesByScore = score => {
  return badges
    .filter(([name, thres]) => score >= thres)
    .map(([name] => name); 
};

getBadgesByScore(daniel.score); // ["gold", "silver"...
```

Using object properties might be conceptually simple, but you're storing a lot of duplicate data.

Comment: So you think it would be more effective to create nested arrays? The code after the return statement confused me a bit. What is the filter and map method doing to the array?

Comment: @Gabbykun555 that code is part of the return statement, code after a return statement is unreachable. `filter` returns an array of items that pass the predicate test `score >= threshold` and `map` 'maps' a function over an array (in this case it pulls out the first element of the subarray: the name of the badge). As for effectiveness, I recommend that you value the simplicity of the code over how well it maps to your conception of the objects. When you look at this 3-6 months from now your conception of the problem domain may have changed, but simple code is still simple.

Comment: ...(cont) to give a more concrete example of what I'm talking about, one of my first assignments in college was to implement a card game in Python. I did this big OO thing where every card was an instance that inherited from a class chain. It was basically untyped Java. After we handed it in, the professor showed us his code which was a couple of loops over a simple list that used modulus offsets to get the 'column' of the card. It was like 12 lines to my 100+. His code had almost nothing to do with modelling cards but was short, fast, and most importantly a correct implementation of the game.